# char from ldap not displaying correctly in java

Tags: java, ldap

In the Eclipse Ldap Browser plugin, I see an attribute value that has a UTF-8 char (a lowercase n with a ~ above it).  This is UTF char c3b1 or USC2 char 00F1 which I've read Java uses for its Strings.  But when I print it out to the log file with the following code, it shows up as an uppercase A with a ~ above it, followed by a +/- symbol.  All three output statements show the same thing.

```
    while(allAttributes.hasNext()) {
        LDAPAttribute attribute =  (LDAPAttribute)allAttributes.next();    
        String attributeValue = new String(attribute.getStringValue());
        byte[] attByteValue = attribute.getByteValue();
        String utf8Str = new String( attByteValue, "UTF-8");
        log.debug("attribute.getStringValue="+attribute.getStringValue());
        log.debug("attributeValue="+attributeValue);
        log.debug("utf8Str="+utf8Str);
        boolean isValidUTF8 = Base64.isValidUTF8(attByteValue, true);
        if (isValidUTF8) log.debug("string contains all valid UTF8 chars and UCS2 chars");
        else log.debug("string contains invalid UTF8 char(s) or invalid UCS2 char(s)");
    }
```

isValidUTF returns true so it seems there are no invalid chars.  Any suggestions how to make it display correctly in the log?

Comment: It may be an issue with the application you're using to read the log.  Try using something like Notepad++ where you can specify the encoding.

Comment: I'm using vi on linux.  Whatever is causing this is also causing hibernate to write the wrong chars to oracle, which overflows the field.

Comment: Its seeing utf8 char c3b1 and converting it to USC2 chars 00c3 and 00b1 which are A~ and +/- symbols, respectively